# How to find all every element between text Python

Tags: python

I'd like to know how to find characters in between texts in python. What I mean is that you have for example:

```py
cool_string = "I am a very cool string here is something: not cool 8+8 that's it"
```

and I want to save to another string everything in between something: to that's it.
So the result would be:

```py
soultion_to_cool_string = ' not cool 8+8 '
```

Comment: `cool_string[cool_string.index(':')+1: cool_string.index("that's it")]`

Comment: Jame's slice approach or look into Python's `.splt()` string method. For more advanced parsing, you may want to eventually look into regular expressions but the current version should not require it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)

```py
start = "something:"
end = "that's it"

cool_string[cool_string.find(start) + len(start):cool_string.find(end)]
```

If you need to remove empty space [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into regex it will do your job. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Now for your question we will first require the lookahead and lookbehind expressions

The lookahead:

Asserts that what immediately follows the current position in the string is foo.

Syntax: (?=foo)

The lookbehind:

Asserts that what immediately precedes the current position in the string is foo.

Syntax: (?<=foo)

We need to look behind for `something:` and lookahead for `that's it`

```
import re
regex = r"(?<=something:).*?(?=that\'s it)"  # .*? is way to capture everything in b/w except line terminators
re.findall(regex, cool_string)
```